# Copying object values not referencing

Tags: java, search

```
public class Track {int size; int count; Luggage front; Luggage rear}

class Luggage {String name; Luggage next; Luggage prev;}

class Cart {int position; Luggage luggage;}

class Step {
   Cart cart; 
   Track track[]; 
   String moves = "";}
```

I'm trying to make a program that hard-force solves a solution. For that I queue elements in a queue with all different moves that can be made via STEP. There are 5 different moves that you can make each turn and STEP keeps all the values inside, but the values inside STEP are objects that further point to objects.

How do I copy an object Step, which contains further references to objects inside? (each turn I have to make 5 new different STEPs from the STEP that was in this turn)

Comment: Have you tried queue in collections api

Comment: create a constructor that takes te original Step and creates (new) copies of fields as needed: `Step(Step original)` - very similar like it is done with some collections e.g. `ArrayList(Collection...)`. Eventually it would be better to have one Step referencing the previous one, kind of a linked list...

Comment: I just made Step(Step org), Track(Track.org...)... for each object that is inside step and is gonna get cloned... :)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, in Java you can `clone()` objects that implement the `Cloneable` interface. However, the default implementation of `clone()` only performs a shallow copy (for example, if your object contains an array, a copy of the array will be made, but not of elements within the array). If you want to perform a deep clone, you will have to override the `clone()` method to do it yourself (you usually want to override `clone()` anyway to make it public as it's protected by default).